# How to use the constant rank theorem to show that there is no $C^1$ surjection $f : U \subset \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ for $n < m$?

Tags: real-analysis

In a homework problem sheet, I had to prove that, if $f : U \to \mathbb R^m$ is a continuously differentiable surjection defined on an open subset $U \subset \mathbb R^n$, then $n \ge m$. The instructor intended us to use the constant rank theorem.

I did not see the instructor's intended solution. Instead, I used the fact that $f$ is locally Lipschitz to show that, if $n < m$, then $f(U)$ has measure zero, and therefore cannot be the whole of $\mathbb R^m$.

I am not going to change the solution I submitted, because it took me a lot of effort to come up with it already, and technically it *does* solve the problem. However, I would still like to know how this problem could have been solved using the constant rank theorem alone, without using any measure theory.

---

Suppose that $n < m$. Then $df_p$ is not surjective for any $p \in U$.

Since we intend to use the constant rank theorem, we initially restrict our attention to the points where the constant rank theorem can indeed be used. By definition, $p \in U$ is one such point if and only if it has a neighborhood $V_p \subset U$ such that the restriction $df \mid V_p$ has constant rank.

By the constant rank theorem, we may shrink each $V_p$ so that, after applying suitable changes of coordinates to both the domain and the codomain, $f \mid V_p$ admits a local representation of the form

$$(x_1, \dots, x_n) \longmapsto (x_1, \dots, x_k, 0, \dots, 0)$$

If $n < m$, then $k < m$, hence $f(V_p)$ is a meager subset of $\mathbb R^m$, in the sense of the Baire category theorem.

Now consider the set $V = \bigcup_p V_p$. By construction, $\{ V_p \}$ is an uncountable open cover of $V$. However, $V$ is Lindelöf, so we may replace $\{ V_p \}$ with a countable subcover. Therefore $f(V) = \bigcup_p f(V_p)$ is itself meager, because it is a countable union of meager subsets of $\mathbb R^m$.

This is fine and well, but I cannot for my life see why $f(U \setminus V)$ should be in some sense a “small” subset of $\mathbb R^m$ as well, other than using the measure-theoretic argument above. I did try some ideas, unsuccessfully:

- Show that, if $p$ admits a neighborhood $V_p$ in which the rank of $df$ does not exceed $k$, then we may shrink $V_p$ so that $f(V_p)$ is contained in a $C^1$ submanifold of $\mathbb R^m$ of dimension $k$.

  This does not work. Consider the function $\gamma : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^3$ defined by

  $$\gamma(t) = (t, e^{-1/t^2} u(-t), e^{-1/t^2} u(t))$$

  where $u(t)$ is the characteristic function of the positive reals. Then $\gamma$ is of class $C^\infty$. Any putative $V_0$ may be shrunk to $I_\varepsilon = (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ for some arbitrarily small $\varepsilon$. However, $\gamma(I_\varepsilon)$ is not contained in any $C^1$ submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$ of dimension $1$. It is too “pointy” at the origin.
- <strike>Show that, if $p$ admits a neighborhood $V_p$ in which the rank of $df$ does not exceed $k$, then we may shrink $V_p$ so that, after applying suitable changes of coordinates, $df$ contains a fixed $k \times k$ minor such that every entry outside this minor is zero.</strike>

  I have absolutely no idea how to prove this, or whether it is even true. However, I suspect that any counterexamples to the previous item should also be counterexamples to this one.
- Show that every $p$ admits neighborhood $V_p$ such that, after applying suitable changes of coordinates, $df$ contains a minor that is a diagonal matrix (or maybe in some sense “diagonally dominant”), and every entry outside this minor is zero.

  I have no idea how to prove this, or whether it is even true.

Could someone give me a hint?

---

<strike>**EDIT:** Maybe this works. Prove that $V$ is dense in $U$.</strike>

All of this is leading me to the conclusion that the nice continuous surjections are those that are open maps. For example, if we let $X$ be the set of real numbers equipped with the discrete topology, then the identity function $f : X \to \mathbb R$ is a surjection, but sure as hell it locally does not look like one.

(Note that being a continuously differentiable open surjection is a strictly weaker condition than being a continuously differentiable submersion, e.g., consider the map $z \mapsto z^2$ in the complex plane.)

But then, $X$ is a rather weird object and not a manifold in the first place. If we consider spaces that can actually arise in practice, the closest thing to a non-open continuously differentiable surjection $f : M \to N$ is to take a foliation of $N$, and then identify $M$ with the disjoint union of countably many leaves. However, this still fails to be a surjection.

---

Since the original problem I posed is rather hard and I am starting to lose interest in it, I will post the original motivation for this question. The instructor claims that the following is a good enough proof.

> By assumption, $f$ is surjective. If we take any open subset $B \subset \mathbb R^m$, and let $W = f^{-1}(B)$ be its preimage, then the restriction $f \mid W : W \to B$ is still surjective.

So far so good.

> In particular, take a point $p \in U$ such that the rank of $df_p$ is maximal, and let $B$ be a neighborhood of $f(p)$. Then, after shrinking $B$, there exists a neighborhood $V_p$ of $p$ such that the restriction $f \mid V_p : V_p \to B$ admits a local representation of the form
>
> $$(x_1, \dots, x_n) \mapsto (x_1, \dots, x_k, 0, \dots, 0)$$

So far so good. Then he makes what I think is a dubious step.

> Since $f \mid V_p$ is surjective, then $m = k \le n$.

The problem is that $V_p$ need not be the whole of $W$. After all, we obtained $V_p$ by shrinking $W$! Or maybe he claims that we have redefined $B = f(V_p)$? Then $B$ need not be an open subset of $\mathbb R^m$ anymore! (This will turn out to be the case, but we cannot assume the conclusion.)

To summarize: We know that $f \mid W : W \to B$ is surjective. But we do *not* know that $f \mid V_p : V_p \to B$ is surjective.

Or maybe I am wrong and someone could tell me why?

Comment: I like your locally Lipschitz argument (I have essentially that as an exercise in my multivariable analysis book for use with integration). I would be curious to see how your instructor's proof goes. Aside from a strengthening of Sard's theorem, in fact, I don't see how you handle points around which $f$ fails to have constant rank. Indeed, without the $C^1$ assumption, the ultimate result is false, so it's very subtle.

Comment: @TedShifrin: I particularly enjoyed the moment when I realized that the Lipschitz condition that relates the radii of an open ball in the domain with an open ball in the codomain, could be reexpressed as a relation between their volumes.

Comment: Well, I wanted cubes (for integration) rather than balls, but, yes. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin: Of course, by “balls”, I meant “balls of the maximum norm”, i.e. cubes! In fact, at some point I said: “Until now, we have not cared much about the norms on $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$. From now onwards, we shall use the maximum norm, because it is easy to split cubes into subcubes without increasing their total volume.”

Comment: Oh, very cool, although balls are in fact more natural given the usual (operator) norm we use on linear maps. So you have to relate cubes to balls anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

If you invoke **Sard's Theorem**, then this problem is easy to solve: since $m > n$, the set of critical points must be $U$, but since $f$ is surjective, $f(U) = \Bbb R^m$. But this means that the set of critical values $f(U)$ does not have lebesgue measure zero which is a contradiction.

Comment: Sard's theorem is an even stronger result than what I proved in my homework. And we are back to using measure-theoretic concepts.